# Получить названия metal-групп, имеющих в составе несколько гитаристов

Tags: java, xml, xpath

вот пример xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <music>
    <style type="rock">
        <band id="1">
            <name>Led Zeppelin</name>
            <genre>Hard Rock</genre>
            <cast>
                <artist type="vocal">Robert Plant</artist>
                <artist type="drums">John Bonham</artist>
                <artist type="bass">John Paul Jones</artist>
               <artist type="guitar">Jimmy Page</artist>
            </cast>
        </band>

        <band id="2">
            <name>Scorpions</name>
            <genre>Heavy Metal</genre>
            <cast>
                <artist type="rhythm guitar">Rudolf Schenker</artist>
                <artist type="lead guitar">Matthias Jabs</artist>
                <artist type="bass">Pawel Maciwoda</artist>
            </cast>
        </band>
    </style>
</music>
```

а вот пример метода...только мне тут необходимо получить лишь те группы, которые необходимы по условию "получить названия metal-групп, имеющих в составе несколько гитаристов"

```java
private void printNamesOfMetalBandsWithSomeGuitarists(Document document) {
    System.out.println("\n2. Printing names of metal bands with some guitarists");

    List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/music/style/band[genge[text()='Hard Rock']]/name"); //  <-- here

    nodes.stream().map(n -> n.getStringValue()).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"/music/style/band[genre=('Hard Rock' or 'Heavy Metal') and count(cast/artist[contains(@type,'guitar')]) &gt; 1]/name"
```

Выражение получается весьма сложным.

---

```
genre=('Hard Rock' or 'Heavy Metal')
```

Добавьте в список те жанры, которые считаете *металлическими*.

---

```
count( ... ) &gt; 1
```

Это означает количество больше одного.

---

```
contains(@type,'guitar')
```

Атрибут `type` содержит значение `guitar`. Басисты в пролёте...
При желании можно и их добавить с помощью `or`.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее Xpath выражение.

При условии что несколько = один или больше.

**XPath**

```
/music/style/band[genre=('Hard Rock','Heavy Metal') and cast/artist[contains(@type,'guitar')]]/name
```